# Scientific Lawyer (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My first riddle received pretty good reaction, so I'm trying a new one. The riddle goes like this:

> My prefix is an amphibian,
>
> My suffix heavier than you.
>
> My infix abbreviates the thing the suffix describes,
>
> And the whole word is a scientist and a lawyer.

Comment: is it a name? as in the name of a scientist and a lawyer?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Newton

My prefix is an amphibian,

> Newt

My suffix heavier than you.

> Ton

My infix abbreviates the thing the suffix describes,

> Wt - abbreviation of weight

And the whole word is a scientist and a lawyer.

> Newton developed the *Laws* of Motion.

Comment: Wow so quick?!!! You got the answer!!!

Comment: that was fast !!

Comment: Just read this and had the same thought :)

Comment: This is easy, isn't it?